# Do you need to assign a worker dyno for database queries in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I understand that you assign dynos to tasks. Web, worker, or others.

My question is:  for Postgres queries, like,
    @User.all
Do I need to assign a dyno to a worker for that? Or is the querying of mongo or sql databases in heroku solely depend on code of the application?

I know one hobby dyno assigned to web would suffice for them, but not sure if I need another hobby dyno for PSQL queries.

App info: It's about 4 people just running searches for the type of employees they have and querying stuff like what languages they speak, availability, skills, etc to sell to their clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort Answer: No you don't need to assign a dyno to it

Longer Answer: When you run a command to connect to heroku (like `heroku run rails c` or `heroku pg:psql`) it will create a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works) attached to your terminal. From there you can do anything you could do in the your rails console or Postgres shell locally, but with access to your heroku database. They even destroy the dyno for you when you disconnect. What a great service!

Comment: That's great! I deploy to heroku just to build my resume, and practice building applications. But I realized I needed a bit more of a deeper understanding for pricing. So let me get this straight, even if it's $7 a month for a hobby dyno. I only pay $7 if it were to run 24/7 for 24 hours? And if it is not active I only pay for when it is running?